# Setting up /boot on USB for encrypted partition

Tags: boot, usb, partitioning, debian, encryption

I installed an encrypted LVM with Debian Jessie on an extended partition and setup a USB Boot Key Disk to load into the system. However, when I boot into the USB it just shows a black screen with a blinking cursor.

I'd like to know if this is because it is an extended and not primary partition, and, if there is something wrong with the files in the USB, how can I reinstall or modify them.

Answer (score 1):

Grub probably is not well installed or not installed at all, try to found another live linux (usb or cd ) and check with the disk manager if the partition exist and is ok.

If is, follow this:

https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall

Comment: I boot into the Legacy BIOS option. I don't think that's the problem

Comment: You still need the GRUB anyway.